# Не получается перезаписать количество элементов

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, счетчики

Приветствую. Есть пример в [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ls0wq6v1/16/), где отражена товарная секция, в которой можно увеличивать/уменьшать количество товаров. У меня не получается в случае, если названия товаров совпадают - найти соответствие в `.cart_list li` и перезаписать их количество, а также, чтобы сумму всех товаров переопределялась в зависимости от изменения количества элементов.

```js
function parseNumber(str) {
  var regExp = /\d+/g;
  var part;
  var result = 0;
  while (part = regExp.exec(str)) {
    result = result * Math.pow(10, part[0].length) + parseInt(part[0]);
  }
  return result;
}

function numberWithCommas(n) {
  var parts = n.toString().split(".");
  return parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + (parts[1] ? "." + parts[1] : "");
}
var summary = 0;

$('#foot-carousel').find('>').remove();

var test = $('.test:last');

$('.cart_list li').each(function() {
  console.log('x');
  $('#foot-carousel').append(test.clone());
});

console.log($('.li').length);

$('.li').each(function() {

  var $this = $(this);
  console.log($this);
  var quantity = $this.find(".quantity").text().match(/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/g);
  var basePrice = "";
  for (var i = 1; i < quantity.length; i++) {
    basePrice += quantity[i];
  }
  basePrice = parseNumber(basePrice);
  var $input = $this.find(".input-text.qty.text");
  var max = +$input.attr("max");
  var min = +$input.attr("min");

  function updateValue(newValue) {
    console.log(newValue);
    var value = +newValue;
    console.log(value);
    newValue > max && (value = max);
    newValue < min && (value = min);
    var item = value * basePrice;
    summary = summary + item;
    $this.find(".amount").text(numberWithCommas(value * basePrice) + " руб");
    $this.find(".quantity")[0].firstChild.data = value + " × ";
    $(".summary").text(numberWithCommas(summary) + " руб");
    var product = $(this).find('.product-name').text();
    $('.cart_list li').each(function() {
      if ($(this).find('.product-name').text() == product) {
        $(this).find(".quantity")[0].firstChild.data = value + " × ";
      }
    });
    $input.val(value);
    console.log(value);
  }

  $this.find(".plus").click(function() {
    console.log("plus");
    updateValue(+$input.val() + 1);

  });

  $this.find(".minus").click(function() {
    console.log("minus");
    updateValue(+$input.val() - 1);

  });

  $input.change(function() {
    console.log("change");
    console.log(this.value);
    updateValue($input.val());
  });
  updateValue(quantity[0]);
});

$(".fixed-bottom").show().fadeTo("slow");
```

```html
<!--здесь у нас берутся элементы-->
<ul class="cart_list">
  <li>
    <div class="product-name">Товар 1</div><span class="quantity">2 × <span class="amount">1.440.000 руб</span></span>
    <br />
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="product-name">Товар 2</div><span class="quantity">2 × <span class="amount">1.440.000 руб</span></span>
    <br />
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="product-name">Товар 3</div><span class="quantity">2 × <span class="amount">1.440.000 руб</span></span>
    <br />
  </li>
</ul>
<!--итоговая сумма всех элементов-->
<p>Итого..........<span class="summary"><strong>416.000</strong></span>
</p>
<!--здесь они получаются в результате скрипта-->
<div id="foot-carousel"></div>

<div class="li test">
  <div class="product-name">Товар 1</div><span class="quantity">2 × <span class="amount">1.440.000 руб</span></span>
  <div class="quantity buttons_added">
    <input type="number" step="1" min="1" max="100" id="num_count" name="quantity" value="1" title="Кол." class="input-text qty text" size="4" />
    <input type="button" value="+1" id="button_plus" class="plus" />
    <input type="button" value="-1" id="button_minus" class="minus" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Regent может быть вас не затруднит мне подсказать где я ошибся?

Comment: Это очень сложно и громозко. Не понимаю, зачем так. Я бы делал Object типа такого: `{'good 1': {price: 1440, quantity: 2}}`. По клику сразу бы можно было найти товар по названию в Object и изменить любой параметр. После чего запустить функцию пересчёта корзины, где простым перебором пройтись по всем элементам Object и отрендерить табличку. Вообще, Knockout.js умеет делать подобные вещи налету. А перебор Object хорошо умеет делать [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs) во всех вариациях. Если нужно, могу накидать примеры

Comment: @Bulkin "Это очень сложно и громозко." потому что это woocommerce на wordpress и с ним приходится работать..
Спасибо, уже решил вопрос)

Comment: Понял, не дурак. Был бы дурак, не понял ☺